# Toggling a hidden Section by following an anchor link that points to inside the section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a game rules website, and felt like one way of improving the UX would be to make larger sections (and, if I can get this working, maybe smaller sub-sections) start out collapsed, but be expandable by clicking on their section titles (usually an H1 tag, but maybe H2 or H3 as well). Worked great, but then I realized I have a lot of anchor links to divs with ID attributes that are within the larger sections, which don't trigger the toggle functionality.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
function secToggle(i) {
  if (i.style.display === "none") {
    i.style.display = "block"
  } else {
    i.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.secToggle {
  display: none;
  border: 1px dotted transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

section:target {
  display: block;
}

.secToggle:hover {
  border-color: black;
}

.secToggleHeading:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.secToggle:focus-within {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Test link: <a href="#SpecificTopic">Click Here</a></p>

<h1 class="secToggleHeading" id="Subject1" onclick="secToggle(secSubject1)">Header 1</h1>
<section class="secToggle" id="secSubject1">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <p id="SpecificTopic">Specific Topic</p>
  <p>Some other content</p>
</section>
```

I wanted to non-intrusively call out what each section entailed, so the user knows which content is enclosed by the section they may want to collapse back down, hence the dotted border and `:hover`.

As you can see, I played a little bit with `:target` and `:focus-within`, but neither seems to have any effect. I have a feeling I need to do this with JS (and if a library, preferably JQuery), but every google search permutation I try comes back with answers to more simplistic questions similar to this one.

I'll also mention that I have the "need to click once to activate the onclick event before the divs are actually toggleable" issue I need to correct as well, but I feel like that's just a matter of choosing which of the several solutions I found. Still, figured I'd mention it in case it was somehow involved in solving this one.

Comment: You may want to learn about the html [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) element which already does this and without any JavaScript.

Comment: Here's a fiddle using the above suggested `<details>` with a #link inside the content: https://jsfiddle.net/bws7p6h5/

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use `<details>` then you can add a click handler to all `"a[href^='#']"` with `$("#" + this.href.split("#")[1]).closest(".secToggle").slideDown();` to ensure the destination section is visible.   Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bws7p6h5/1/

Comment: The *need to click twice for first activation* issue is due to your check for `if (i.style.display === "none") {` - debug what `i.style.display` is - on first click it will be blank/null as it's hidden by css, not by inline style - so first click => else and hides it (but it's already hidden) - so you need to click again to show it.  Change the `if` to `if (i.style.display !== "block") {` then it will pick up the default (blank) as well as "none"

Comment: Whoa---this is fantastic!!  @Yogi `<details>` does _exactly_ what I'm after with the collapsible sections (and, by its nature, also resolves the "need to click twice" issue!), and @freedomn-m that fiddle not only shows that it handles my specific issue, but that I can also use other tags within both `<details>` and `<summary>`!

I'm still what I would call in the "beginner" stages of learning webdev, but even so, I think this has inspired me to take a review of as many tags as I can---I had no idea Details as a tag existed!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be achieved with the `html` `details` element which already does this and without any JavaScript (see [Details disclosure element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

The code below demonstrates how and when the `details` expands when activated in this way via a click.

Linking to the `id` of the `details` element itself does not expand the content, whereas linking to an `id` within the `details` element does expand the content.

In addition, it is possible to style the content of the `details` element, for example, by wrapping the content in a `div` and applying a `border` and `background` color using `CSS`.

```css
summary {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

details>div {
  border: solid 2px black;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#SpecificSummary">LINK: Click to go to the summary/header and expand the content</a></p>
<p><a href="#SpecificHeader">LINK: Click to go to the summary/header without expanding content</a></p>
<p><a href="#SpecificTopic">LINK: Click to go to a specific topic within the summary</a></p>

<h4>Before clicking on the links above, collapse the content below by clicking on the down arrow (see below in the middle of the Lorem ipsum text)</h4>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur enim eveniet ratione voluptatum! Accusamus amet beatae, consequatur cupiditate ducimus enim ex inventore iure laborum, necessitatibus nesciunt porro quasi quibusdam quos rem repellat
  sapiente tempore voluptates?
</p>
<p>
  Asperiores aut deleniti expedita hic inventore laudantium nam placeat praesentium quaerat quas, quis saepe voluptatibus. Ad aliquid animi consectetur deleniti ducimus earum ex illo illum ipsum itaque laboriosam magnam minima necessitatibus nemo nobis
  officiis omnis quia recusandae repellendus rerum sequi similique soluta tempora tenetur, unde velit voluptas! Ab accusantium ad commodi, dolores ea eaque numquam, placeat quasi quisquam, reiciendis sapiente totam veritatis vero.
</p>
<p>
  Aliquam dolore incidunt officia quis unde! Alias atque debitis ducimus excepturi fugiat ipsa nesciunt nisi, nostrum placeat totam. Ad consequatur facere incidunt nam quod repudiandae. Aut dolorum ea eos esse est facere fuga labore laboriosam libero officia,
  officiis praesentium recusandae vero? Corporis eius impedit incidunt molestiae quos. Assumenda nemo perferendis possimus quam repellendus rerum, unde! Delectus, dicta expedita hic inventore placeat quaerat reprehenderit similique vel velit voluptatibus!
  Ab aperiam fugiat magnam omnis recusandae sunt voluptas! Ad adipisci asperiores aspernatur autem deserunt dolore error est, excepturi facilis fugit ipsa molestias nihil nobis non nostrum numquam possimus quaerat rerum sint tempore, unde vitae voluptatem.
</p>

<details id="SpecificHeader">
  <summary id="SpecificSummary">This is a summary or header</summary>
  <div>
    <p>Some content</p>
    <p id="SpecificTopic">Specific topic</p>
    <p>Some other content</p>
  </div>
</details>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur enim eveniet ratione voluptatum! Accusamus amet beatae, consequatur cupiditate ducimus enim ex inventore iure laborum, necessitatibus nesciunt porro quasi quibusdam quos rem repellat
  sapiente tempore voluptates? Asperiores aut deleniti expedita hic inventore laudantium nam placeat praesentium quaerat quas, quis saepe voluptatibus. Ad aliquid animi consectetur deleniti ducimus earum ex illo illum ipsum itaque laboriosam magnam minima
  necessitatibus nemo nobis officiis omnis quia recusandae repellendus rerum sequi similique soluta tempora tenetur, unde velit voluptas! Ab accusantium ad commodi, dolores ea eaque numquam, placeat quasi quisquam, reiciendis sapiente totam veritatis
  vero.
</p>
<p>
  Aliquam dolore incidunt officia quis unde! Alias atque debitis ducimus excepturi fugiat ipsa nesciunt nisi, nostrum placeat totam. Ad consequatur facere incidunt nam quod repudiandae. Aut dolorum ea eos esse est facere fuga labore laboriosam libero officia,
  officiis praesentium recusandae vero? Corporis eius impedit incidunt molestiae quos.
</p>
<p>
  Assumenda nemo perferendis possimus quam repellendus rerum, unde! Delectus, dicta expedita hic inventore placeat quaerat reprehenderit similique vel velit voluptatibus! Ab aperiam fugiat magnam omnis recusandae sunt voluptas! Ad adipisci asperiores aspernatur
  autem deserunt dolore error est, excepturi facilis fugit ipsa molestias nihil nobis non nostrum numquam possimus quaerat rerum sint tempore, unde vitae voluptatem.
</p>
```